# How to add indoor map on xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a  mall store-navigation mobile apps on a cross-platform using xamarin, My question is how to add an indoor mapping for Xamarin forms. I would appreciate any help.
I attach sample image from google result.[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwXxy.jpg)

Comment: This is too general question. Can you give some more information of what you are trying to achieve by posting some code that you have already written?

Comment: @kosnik My apology, I'm new in mobile development, so far I wrote code to display some list of shops, but I want to add a page where I can put the maps so users can navigate where they are inside the mall. With that, i want to know if this is possible xamarin c# or someone here had achieved it,

Answer (score 0):

You should add the nuget Package [Xamarin.Forms.Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Maps) into all of your projects, including your Class Library.

Then, in Android, in your `MainActivity`  do the initialisation:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle); 
FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle); // After forms Init
```

In iOS, in your `AppDelegate.cs`

```
FormsMaps.Init();
```

In your Android Project, under `AndroidManifest.xml` add your reference to your Maps API Key (search google for how to get a API key):

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
           android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
```

Also, add the permissions needed for acessing localisation:

```
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS
ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
INTERNET
```

To create a Map in a Page is as simple as:

```
<maps:Map MapType="Street" />
```

Comment: The OP is asking about INDOOR navigation so I think https://developers.arcgis.com/example-apps/indoor-routing-xamarin/ would be more suitable for him.